# lxml - scraping text within cluttered php

Tags: web-scraping, lxml

I'm in the process of rewriting a poorly written website that was originally coded in php.

I'm trying to isolate the text within a p tag and was wondering how I can take just the text portions. Any ideas?

```
<p>
<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">

<br>
TEXT SAMPLE 1
<br>
<br>
TEXT SAMPLE 2

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">TEXT SAMPLE 3
</span>,

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">&nbsp;TEXT SAMPLE 4
</span>&nbsp;TEXT SAMPLE 5

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">.&nbsp;</span>

</span><span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">

<br>
<br>

TEXT SAMPLE 6
</span>

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">&nbsp;</span>

TEXT SAMPLE 7
```

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a good place to start.  Especially the [get_text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function.

This will output all the text in the snippet above:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

CONTENT = """
<p>
<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">

<br>
TEXT SAMPLE 1
<br>
<br>
TEXT SAMPLE 2

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">TEXT SAMPLE 3
</span>,

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">&nbsp;TEXT SAMPLE 4
</span>&nbsp;TEXT SAMPLE 5

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">.&nbsp;</span>

</span><span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">

<br>
<br>

TEXT SAMPLE 6
</span>

<span lang="EN-IE" xml:lang="EN-IE">&nbsp;</span>

TEXT SAMPLE 7
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    soup = BeautifulSoup(CONTENT)
    print soup.get_text()
```

The output may need some string manipulation, as there are many new lines, but that will strip away the HTML.